# How many 5-letter combinations can I make using only As, Bs, Cs, and Ds that don't contain the letters CAB next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I will add in that repetition is allowed also. So what I got is 4*4*3*4*4=768 total combinations. Since you can't have 4 options for the third space since that could potentially cause CAB to be next to each other. Did I figure this out correctly?

Comment: The problem is that sometimes you do have $4$ options for the third letter, for example when the first, second, fourth and fifth letters are all the same.  BTW it's not clear to me whether the letters CAB have to come in that order.  Is ABC okay or prohibited?

Comment: [Explicit counting](https://tio.run/##RcsxCoRADADA3lekyy6IICLYXKHeRw5dMaJJiLHw9StXWQ@jt6/CTaeWMx0q5kCezEX2s1Aj9nBeR6hhEQMC4pcrNZmvyQP2w/jFEixp@vmnjUAL4NgPCCz@P4jVJsSBYow5Pw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") if only 'CAB' is not allowed, gives $976$. Btw, it's much more simple to count combinations that _do_ have 'CAB' and then subtract.

Comment: Yes, CAB have to come in that order, anything else is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s look at this another way! 
All possible words with 5 letters using A , B , C and D are :
4*4*4*4*4 = 1024

Now treat CAB as a package! And count all the 5-letter words containing this package. 
We have 4*4 (choosing the two other letters) * 3 (the package can be in three places) 
So 4*4*3 = 48

Finally the answer would be : 1024-96=976

Comment: 3! should just be 3. Once you've chosen the two other letters (with order), there are only 3 possible places for the package to go. It can go before the two letters, in between, or after.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I worked through it, I got CAB in 3 possible places, so I took 1024 (total possibilities) and subtracted all possibilities that CAB could appear. Therefore 4*4*3=48. Giving me 1024-48=976. Or am I forgetting something?

Comment: @Archr thanks for bringing it up :)

Comment: @Matt L. You’re welcome! You’re totally right! I edited the answer! Sorry for the mistake:)